# Embedding ETH Wallet Address into Webpage

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, erc-20

Hey is there a quick way to embed an `Ethereum` wallet address and a `button` into my existing website so as to allow people to send in their `ETH` donations to me?

Or do I need to go through the whole `npm install` *everything-in-the-world* process, meaning `web3`, `HD-wallet-provider`, etc., then write up a whole contract, include the `ABI` code in my `.js` file - just to allow this fairly simple `sendTransaction` functionality?

Or am I over-thinking this?

Comment: Add web3.js to the page. Follow MetaMask's instructions for wiring things up (getting users to grant you access). Then it's a one-liner: `web3.eth.sendTransaction({ to: ..., from: ..., value: ... });`.

Comment: @smarx  Hey that worked! Thank you!  Now, I'd like to give you credit for providing the right answer, but I can't since you posted it here as a "comment" and not as an answer.  Can you re-post so I can credit you?

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use Whois0x.io, it provides a link with an identity card you set up with keybase style self post on social media. It's easier for people to donate if they do know for sure who is the receiver. 
It can give you something like this:
[0xfFA7A52a7d30E5Bc81c031a717726FA638c76289](https://whois0x.io/?query=0xfFA7A52a7d30E5Bc81c031a717726FA638c76289)

Then, if people connect their metamask account or their Dapp browser account (Trust wallet, Wallet,..), they just have to click send and validate.